# Reporting Service SQL Server 2008 not deploying

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, report

I have two pairs of servers, one web server one DB server in each pair. I installed SQL Server 2008 in my DB servers and everything works, but reporting services only works in one.

In one of my servers, reporting service refuses to deploy my reports to http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ReportServer and says "Unable to deploy the server check to make sure target url is correct..." However it works fine in the other server.

What are the possible conditions for a reporting service to refuse deployment??

Does it require IIS to deploy? Are there some sort of port 80 restrictions on one of the servers making it unable to deploy?

Any ideas??

Comment: "Does it require IIS to deploy? " - SSRS 2K8, No.

Comment: So what would not allow deployment? Is there a list of requirements before being able to deploy a report server/service?

Comment: Here is a link with the requirements to install and deploy a report with ssrs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143736(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: It's a longshot, but do you have any DNS redirects in place, are you using clustering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your rights on the server you can't deploy to.

also, go onto the server where you can't deploy to and double check the url for the web service in reporting services configuration